# How to find same day of last year after considering holiday/weekend?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to find same day of last year after considering holiday/weekend? Suppose if the date is 12th Jan 2021 then it should find the previous business day of 12th Jan 2020(being a sunday) i.e 10th Jan 2020.

Provided, My date dimension table already has a holiday flag(values like 0 and 1) column which gets updated with Holiday/weekend each year.

Please help me with the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can make assumptions about calendar table, then why not this?

```sql
SELECT MAX(CalendarDate)
FROM dbo.CalendarTable
WHERE CalendarDate <= DATEADD(YEAR,-1, GETDATE())
  AND IsWeekend = 0
  AND IsHoliday = 0;
```